# Simple Immediate Window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, scripting

I'am building a little Immediate Window like the one in Visual Studio. I simply try to compile the Text in a Textedit. Now my Question: how do i get into the Scope of my running program? Is it possible to change Values or Lists of my programm?
Thats my current compile code:

```
    private void SimpleButtonCompileClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CompilerParameters compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters();
        compilerParameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
        compilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
        compilerParameters.TreatWarningsAsErrors = true;
        compilerParameters.CompilerOptions = "/nowarn:1633";
        String sourceCode = "";
        string pattern =
                "\\s*#pragma\\s+reference\\s+\"(?<path>[^\"]*)\"\\s*";
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(sourceCode, pattern);
        if (match.Success)
            compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(match.Groups["path"].Value);
        // Specify .NET version
        Dictionary<string, string> providerOptions =
                new Dictionary<string, string>();
        providerOptions.Add("CompilerVersion", "v3.5");
        CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);
        // Compile source           
        CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParameters, new string[] {sourceCode});
        // Show errors
        if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            String errorString = "";
            foreach (var err in results.Errors)
                errorString += err + "\n";
            XtraMessageBox.Show(errorString);
        }
        else
        {
            // Invoke compiled assembly's entry point
            results.CompiledAssembly.EntryPoint.Invoke
                    (null, new object[0] {});
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have a way (a button? a key combination?) that brings up a form where you can enter the code that you want to compile and execute. Since Invoke is executed in the same process and AppDomain, you can access everything in your running program as long as you have an access point to the thing you want to get to.

For instance it can be a public static variable in one of your classes. Or, to get a particular form, you could use Application.OpenForms and loop through the FormCollection looking for the one with the right Type.